# infinite loop in wp_query using simple query

Tags: wordpress

This code goes into an infinite loop! What am i doing wrong? There is only one post called “hello there”. The only way to stop it is use `break;` in while.

Any help appreciated

```
   $gotop="hello there";

$args = array(

    's' => $gotop,
    'post_type' => 'post'

);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>

        <?php

        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
      $wp_query->the_post();
}

else:
  echo "nothing found.";
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$wp_query` which is global query variable for wordpress so everytime its checking for new post.

Instead of $wp_query use other variable or use below code.

```
$gotop="hello there";

$args = array(

    's' => $gotop,
    'post_type' => 'post'

);

$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>

        <?php

        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
      $custom_query->the_post();
}

else:
  echo "nothing found.";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: the $wp_query was the issue thanks. i renamed it and worked!